# Minimax logic works slow

Tags: python, cs50

I'm programming Tic-Tac-Toe using minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning after taking Harvard's CS-50.
My logic is working perfectly, except for the return time of minimax (especially on the first call, when only one player played). I was thinking of replacing the extra recursive call of minimax to max/min value. I want to emphasize that minimax is taking relatively slow for my purposes (around 0.5 seconds).

```
import math
import copy
import time

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    if board == initial_state():
        return X
    X_counter = 0
    O_counter = 0
    for row in board:
        for cell in row:
            if cell == X:
                X_counter += 1
            elif cell == O:
                O_counter += 1
    return O if X_counter > O_counter else X


def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    possible_moves = set()

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] is None:
                possible_moves.add((i, j))
    return possible_moves


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    newboard = copy.deepcopy(board)
    newboard[action[0]][action[1]] = player(board)
    return newboard


def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """

    if board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] != None:  # 1, 2, 3
        return board[0][0]

    if board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] != None:  # 4, 5, 6
        return board[1][0]

    if board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] != None:  # 7, 8, 9
        return board[2][0]

    if board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] != None:  # 1, 4, 7
        return board[0][0]

    if board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] != None:  # 2, 5, 8
        return board[0][1]

    if board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] != None:  # 3, 6, 9
        return board[0][2]

    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != None:  # 1, 4, 7
        return board[0][0]

    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] != None:  # 3, 5, 7
        return board[0][2]

    return None


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    def check_draw(board):
        for row in board:
            for cell in row:
                if cell is None:
                    return False
        return True

    if winner(board) is not None or check_draw(board):  # or someone won , or there is a draw
        return True
    return False


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    temp = winner(board)
    if temp == X:
        return 1
    elif temp == O:
        return -1
    return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    options = actions(board)
    if player(board) == X:
        vT = -math.inf
        move = set()
        for action in options:
            v, count = minvalue(result(board,action), -math.inf, math.inf, 0)
            if v > vT:
                vT = v
                move = action
    else:
        vT = math.inf
        move = set()
        for action in options:
            v, count = maxvalue(result(board,action), -math.inf, math.inf, 0)
            if v < vT:
                vT = v
                move = action
    return move

def maxvalue(board,alpha,beta,count):
    """
    Calculates the max value of a given board recursively together with minvalue
    """

    if terminal(board): return utility(board), count+1

    v = -math.inf
    posactions = actions(board)

    for action in posactions:
        vret, count = minvalue(result(board, action),alpha,beta,count)
        v = max(v, vret)
        alpha = max(alpha, v)
        if alpha > beta:
            break
    return v, count+1

def minvalue(board,alpha,beta,count):
    """
    Calculates the min value of a given board recursively together with maxvalue
    """

    if terminal(board): return utility(board), count+1

    v = math.inf
    posactions = actions(board)

    for action in posactions:
        vret, count = maxvalue(result(board, action),alpha,beta,count)
        v = min(v, vret)
        beta = min(v, beta)
        if alpha > beta:
            break
    return v, count + 1
```

Comment: Instead of doing `EMPTY = None`, why not just do `None`?

Comment: I didn't even write that variable, it came with the file they provided.

Comment: Oh so there is boilerplate code? Can you indicate which parts were given, and which parts are from your hand? There are several inefficiencies, but it is of course important to know which ones were already there in the boilerplate code.

Comment: In your first move, you have to examine 8! positions, which is 40,320 positions.  I wouldn't worry about 1/2 second.

Comment: OT: Minimax/AB-pruning for tic-tac-toe is hilariously overkill since it is a [solved game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game) - the entire solution space can be pre-computed and should fit in [< 3MB of memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity#Example:_tic-tac-toe_\(noughts_and_crosses\)) assuming 9 bytes per board.

Comment: Only the variables and function definitions were provided.

Comment: I can't use pre-calculated data.

Comment: I do worry about 0.5 seconds, I need a way to examine fewer positions.

Comment: So the return value of `initial_state` does not have to be that list?

Comment: how is this "played"?  `print(minimax(initial_state().copy()))` to get the first move?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: If I'm using the initial_state function, it takes about 7 seconds for the examine 9! positions. So I decided to let the human always start to avoid that.

Comment: For a review of working code like this, really **you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**. This decomposition seems overly complicated and also repeats unnecessary work. For example you don't need to keep calling `player()` and keep recounting the number of pieces played, every single turn. `player()` seems redundant most of the time, you just have a class `Game` containing a list-of-lists `board` and  also keep integer counters `self.X_pieces, self.O_pieces` which each have values 0..3.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than:

```
def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    if board == initial_state():
        return X
    X_counter = 0
    O_counter = 0
    for row in board:
        for cell in row:
            if cell == X:
                X_counter += 1
            elif cell == O:
                O_counter += 1
    return O if X_counter > O_counter else X
```

What kind of performance do you get with:

```
def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    counts = collections.Counter(cell for row in board for cell in row if cell)
    return O if counts.get(X, 0) > counts.get(O, 0) else X
```

A question might arise as to why improving the performance of player might make a big difference.

To calculate the first move, I counted the number of times each method was called:

```
[('winner', 53673), ('player', 30442), ('result', 30441), ('terminal', 30441), ('utility', 23232), ('maxvalue', 16248), ('actions', 14419), ('minvalue', 14193), ('minimax', 1)]
```

We can see that `player()` is called very often. The next candidate to look at is clearly `winner()` as it is called even more frequently than `player()`. We can observe that `winner()` is only ever called by `terminal()` and `utility()`. Further, we can observe that `terminal()` and `utility()` are only ever called together like:

```
if terminal(board): return utility(board), count+1
```

So let's see if we can do something about combining them.

How about:

```
def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    is_winner = winner(board)

    if is_winner == X:
        return 1

    if is_winner == O:
        return -1

    if not actions(board):
        return 0

    return None
```

and we can use it like:

```
who_wins = terminal(board)
if who_wins is not None: return who_wins, count+1
```

This takes the heat off of `winner()`:

```
[('player', 30442), ('result', 30441), ('terminal', 30441), ('winner', 30441), ('maxvalue', 16248), ('actions', 14419), ('minvalue', 14193), ('minimax', 1)]
```

This takes an addition 25% off the already reduced time.

On my system, the original code takes (on average) **2.5 seconds** for a first move. With these simple updates, the same recommended move is generated in **0.001 seconds** on average.

Comment: I don't think that the player function is taking long, rather the minimax function.

Comment: Did you try it? With that version of player the result takes 1/10th the time. `minimax()` calls `player()` and then calls `result()` inside a for loop fore every action. Each `result()` calls `player()`. Also for every "action" `minimax()` calls either `minvalue()` or `maxvalue()` these functions then call call `result()` for every "action".

Comment: Hello, I tried rewriting the player, terminal, and utility functions as you suggested, but there is no significant change in performance. Time did reduce but not enough.